# Windows 7 doesn't boot after removing booting with chrome os

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot, google-chrome, 32-bit

I'm have **Windows7 32bit** PC, where I've booted **chrome OS** **vanilla build** by Hexxeh using USB , run few commands in crosh terminal & later remove the USB after my work. Now when I'm restarting the system again, it's not booting **Windows7** rather it's starting **chromium OS**. I remember during running command '**upgrade**' it displayed some y/n option and did some operation to /dev/sda? Do this command is **real cause** for the problem?

I've seen some links where solution is given to system repair using windows7 disk, but it is displaying **uncompatible version of recovery options**(checked both with 32bit & 64 bit, although it is 32 bit machine). So, anybody knows how to get back to **Windows7**?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "run few commands" - *what* commands exactly?

Comment: "did some operation" - what operation?  It sounds like you installed Chrome OS on sda, if that is where Windows was installed to, then Windows no longer exists on sda.

Comment: @Ramhound - i think you are correct, but is there any way to recover my data that exists on drive?

Comment: @Journeyman - run command sudo bash , wget and upgrade..

Comment: @AmritPalSingh - Use file recover of your choice, be sure not to recover the files, on the same drive your trying to recover from.

Comment: @Ramhound - do fresh installing Win7 will work?

Comment: If you install Windows on `sda` any chance of data recovery will be lost, if you have indeed, replaced Windows with Chrome OS.

Comment: @Ramhound - thanks for all your help, will try to see any options available for recovering data.